# Want to simplify Asterisk SIP message flows

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to implement a SIP UA and to do so, I studied the Asterisk console in debug mode for SIP. I tried to call one extension (A) from another extension (B).

The initial message flow up to the RINGING message, I understood, including the Digest Authentication part.
These are:

```
   (B) >--->INVITE-----[Asterisk]
```

Followed by a series of back-and-forth messages:

```
  401 Unauthorized with NONCE
  ACK
  INVITE with correct Digest
  TRYING
  TRYING
  RINGING
```

After the ringing phone (A) is picked up, I see the following exchange of message:

```
  (A) >----> OK >-----> [Asterisk]  

   (A) <----< ACK<-----< [Asterisk]

                         [Asterisk] >----- OK ------> (B)

   (A) >---(re)INVITE--> [Asterisk] 

                         [Asterisk] <-----ACK-------< (B)

                         [Asterisk] >---(re)INVITE--> (B)

   (A) >---TRYING -----> [Asterisk]

                         [Asterisk] <-----OK--------< (B)

   (A) >-----OK--------> [Asterisk]

   (A) <----ACK--------< [Asterisk]
```

I am writing the UA part on the (B) side and know the SDP for A beforehand and can generate
the SDP for B, which is in my control. My call flow will always be from B to A.
I can control all message going from (B).
How can I reduce the above message flow? Also, I do not fully understand the need for so many messages after the initial SDPs are exchanged until RINGING. Or are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk will do like described in SIP standart(rfc).

You can't remove invites. Only things you can do is do disable early media and enable directmedia/ignore sdp part.

Comment: True. Disabling directmedia saves many messages and in my case, I would like Asterisk to remain in the loop so the option makes sense.  I am unsure about disable early media, I will read on it. As for ignore SDP, I don't know what that implies...  How would endpoints know of media capabilities, port, etc.?

Comment: If you do full-compliant UA, you should support all messages described in RFC. It is much more then you show. If you want "shrinked" UA, you can work with one codec,fixed port, ignore SDP

Comment: All I need is a mechanism to make SIP calls to Asterisk through a Node application server with UDP as transport.  So, just need to support basic INVITE to start with. Once I get that working, I can add a bit more options to the INVITE.  Not intending to build a full-fledged SIP UA.  JS libraries such sip,js, jssip, sipml5 all use websockets as transport. Besides they are too bloated for the limited task I have at hand.